# Чем заменить currentUser?

Tags: meteor

Пишу сайт на meteor.js, на странице есть кнопка авторизации, ее нужно скрывать когда пользователь авторизован.
Делаю так:

```js
{{#if currentUser}}
тут код кнопки
{{/if}}
```

Но если он авторизован, то кнопка появляется на мнгновение, а потом исчезает. Знаю, что это происходит из за того, что метеор не успевает загружать информацию о пользователе. Чем этот код можно заменить?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте встроенный хелпер:

```
{{#if loggingIn}}
    {{>spinner}} //Для использования индикатора загрузки установите meteor add sacha:spin
    //Или просто напишите тут <p>Загрузка..</p>
{{else}}
    {{#if currentUser}}
        //Шаблон для авторизованного пользователя 
    {{else}}
        //Форма входа/регистрации
    {{/if}}
{{/if}}
```

Подробнее в документации: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_loggingin